# Call an xml element as a string without the element being included

Tags: c#, xml, linq-to-xml

I am using XDocument to create and load the xml but when i call an an element to string the element tags get added with it.
So far i have been using

```
string xmlVer = _xml.Root.Element("XMLVersion").Value.ToString().Replace("<XMLVersion>", "").Replace("</XMLVersion", "");
```

works fine just looking for code optimization.

Is there a way to call the "inner" text instead?

Im not having child-node linking problems.

Thanks.

Comment: That's not what i asked nor did it answer my question but thanks.

Comment: Can you show an example of the XML you are using?  If I just do `var xmlVer = _xml.Root.Element("XMLVersion").Value` on a test case I made up, `"<XMLVersion>"` is not included in the string.

Comment: `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"?><root><XMLVersion>1.0.0.1</XMLVersion></root>`
How are you calling it?

Comment: For me the code `string xml = "<root><XMLVersion>1.0.0.1</XMLVersion></root>"; XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(xml); Console.WriteLine(doc.Root.Element("XMLVersion").Value);` outputs `1.0.0.1`.

Comment: To illustrate @dbc's point, see [this fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/wPECoE).  Your problem doesn't seem to exist.

Comment: What you *say*, however, is correct - calling `ToString` on the *element* will give you the tags.  Calling `ToString` on `Value`, as your code does, will give you the 'inner text'.  As an aside, `Value` is a string so there's no need to call `ToString` on it.

Comment: @CharlesMager thanks that's working now